# Wbadmin in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, backup

Can you suggest on how to make this script work?

It is working properly in cmd via this command:

```
wbadmin start systemstatebackup 'backuptarget:"F:"' '-quiet'
```

It is working in cmd running powershell via this command:

```
[powershell] wbadmin start systemstatebackup 'backuptarget:"F:"' '-quiet'
```

But it is not working inside a powershell script (backups.ps1). Im confuse with the use of single and double quotes. The following iteration are not working

backup.ps1

```
$IFMResult2 = "WBADMIN START SYSTEMSTATEBACKUP -backupTarget:E: -quiet" 
$IFMOutput2 = Invoke-Expression $IFMResult2 | out-string -stream

$IFMResult2 = "WBADMIN START SYSTEMSTATEBACKUP 'backuptarget:"F:"' '-quiet'"
$IFMOutput2 = Invoke-Expression $IFMResult2 | out-string -stream
```

Error is 
WBADDMIN Error (Systemstatebackup): the value for option backuptarget is missing

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me but not ask why.
$strBackupDrive = "D:"
$strBackupComand = 'start backup ' + [char[]]45 + 'include:C:\Temp\ ' + [char[]]45 + 'backupTarget:' + $strBackupDrive + ' -quiet'
$errRun = Start-Process wbadmin -ArgumentList $strBackupComand -wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need quotes at all. Try:

```
$Result = & WBADMIN START SYSTEMSTATEBACKUP backuptarget:F: -quiet
```

You can also specify arguments as an array:

```
$Result = & 'WBADMIN' @('START', 'SYSTEMSTATEBACKUP', 'backuptarget:F:', '-quiet')
```

Please note, that you'd better check `$LastExitCode` after `wbadmin` finishes, to verify that there is no errors. Example:

```
$Result = & WBADMIN SYSTEMSTATEBACKUP -backupTarget:F: -quiet

if($LastExitCode)
{
    # Exit code is not null, something gone wrong
}
```

Comment: @lulala Looks like I've missed `:` in drive letter, try again. I'm actually using this code in the script and it works.